# How can I slice my array if my objects are strings

Tags: haskell

I am currently a newbie just starting out.

My code:

```
mySlice :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
mySlice _ [] = []
mySlice n (x:xs)
 | n < 1 = []
 | otherwise = x:mySlice (n-1) xs
```

Actually my code can slice the first index to the number of object I want.

Example: `mySlice 3 [1,2,3,4,5] -- -> [1,2,3]`

But if my objects are strings and not a `Int`, it will return a string and not an array

Example: `mySlice 3 ['1','2','3','4','5'] -- -> "123"`

But what I want is: `mySlice 3 ['1','2','3','4','5'] -- -> ['1','2','3']`

Comment: `['1', '2', '3']` and `"123"` are the same. A `String` is just a list of `Char`s.

Comment: `['1','2','3','4','5']` is a list of `Char` (`[Char]`). In haskell `String`s are `[Char]` so `['1','2','3','4','5'] == "12345"`. The only thing that changes is the look in the terminal, but it is the same thing. If you want a list of `String` you need to use double quotes `["1", "2", ..]`

Comment: `'1`' is a `Char`; `"1" (== ['1'])` is a `String`.

Answer (score 6):

> But if my objects are strings and not a Int, it will return a string and not an array.

`['1', '2', '3']` and `"123"` are the same. A `String` is just a list of `Char`s. Indeed, a `String` is defined as:

```
type String = [Char]
```

It will format a list of `Char`s like `['1', '2', '3']` more compact as `"123"`, but "behind the curtains" it is a list with three elements, the three `Char`s.

Note that `[1,2,3]` is *not* an array, but a list.